# why is EKS Fargate alb controller missing serving-certs/tls.crt?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, eksctl

I have been trying to deploy my application AWS EKS Fargate for the first time over months.
I was getting lots of error but fixed step by step and I got stuck in the following error.

```
{"level":"info","ts":1697396478.544361,"msg":"version","GitVersion":"v2.4.5","GitCommit":"d9482de36bf51a17e7def869f677f35c2b6c6045","BuildDate":"2022-11-09T20:46:04+0000"}
{"level":"info","ts":1697396478.6424556,"logger":"controller-runtime.metrics","msg":"metrics server is starting to listen","addr":":8080"}
{"level":"info","ts":1697396478.656497,"logger":"setup","msg":"adding health check for controller"}
{"level":"info","ts":1697396478.6567256,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"registering webhook","path":"/mutate-v1-pod"}
{"level":"info","ts":1697396478.6568844,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"registering webhook","path":"/mutate-elbv2-k8s-aws-v1beta1-targetgroupbinding"}
{"level":"info","ts":1697396478.6569781,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"registering webhook","path":"/validate-elbv2-k8s-aws-v1beta1-targetgroupbinding"}
{"level":"info","ts":1697396478.6570742,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook","msg":"registering webhook","path":"/validate-networking-v1-ingress"}
{"level":"info","ts":1697396478.6571383,"logger":"setup","msg":"starting podInfo repo"}
{"level":"info","ts":1697396480.6573372,"msg":"starting metrics server","path":"/metrics"}
I1015 19:01:20.657319       1 leaderelection.go:243] attempting to acquire leader lease default/aws-load-balancer-controller-leader...
{"level":"info","ts":1697396480.657604,"logger":"controller-runtime.webhook.webhooks","msg":"starting webhook server"}
E1015 19:01:20.657922       1 leaderelection.go:325] error retrieving resource lock default/aws-load-balancer-controller-leader: Get "https://10.100.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/aws-load-balancer-controller-leader": context canceled
{"level":"error","ts":1697396480.6580412,"logger":"setup","msg":"problem running manager","error":"open /tmp/k8s-webhook-server/serving-certs/tls.crt: no such file or directory"}
```

here is the one of the tutorials I was following. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRODPz9GXb0&t=231s
This tutorial does not have the same issue as I am getting.

So I checked the manifest files and command that I issued are correct.

```bash
> eksctl create cluster --name <cluster name> --version 1.24 --region us-east-1 --fargate --alb-ingress-access
> eksctl utils associate-iam-oidc-provider --region us-east-1 --cluster <cluster name> --approve
> aws iam create-policy --policy-name AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy --policy-document file://iam_policy.json
> eksctl create iamserviceaccount \
  --cluster <cluster name> \
  --region us-east-1 \
  --namespace default \
  --name alb-ingress-controller \
  --attach-policy-arn arn:aws:iam::<accountId>:policy/AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy \
  --approve

> kubectl apply -f full.yaml
> kubectl apply -f alb.yaml

to resolve issue of "controller":"TargetGroupBinding","error":"no matches for kind \"TargetGroupBinding\" in version \"elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1\""
> kubectl apply -k "github.com/aws/eks-charts/stable/aws-load-balancer-controller/crds?ref=master"

to resolve issue of # E1015 17:46:57.040954       1 reflector.go:138] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.21.4/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:alb-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope
> kubectl apply -f rbac-role.yaml
```

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: deployment-2048
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: public.ecr.aws/l6m2t8p7/docker-2048:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: app-2048
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: service-2048
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: ingress-2048
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb   
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing # internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: service-2048
              port:
                number: 80
```

```yaml
# alb.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: alb-ingress-controller
          args:
            - --ingress-class=alb
            - --cluster-name=<cluster name>
            - --aws-vpc-id=<vpc-id>
            - --aws-region=us-east-1
          env:
          image: docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v2.4.5
      serviceAccountName: alb-ingress-controller
```

```yaml
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
      - extensions
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - events
      - ingresses
      - ingresses/status
      - services
      - pods/status
    verbs:
      - create
      - get
      - list
      - update
      - watch
      - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
      - extensions
    resources:
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
      - services
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernates.io/name: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: alb-ingress-controller
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: alb-ingress-controller
    namespace: default
```

I really cannot find what I am missing. the posted youtube link is one of the tutorials I was following.
I tried to follow the aws workshop but no luck so far.
Can someone tell me what I am missing?

I saw the github issues. https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder/issues/1501
but I dont get why I need to edit the application source code to enable webhook?
also tutorials about aws eks fargate, I dont remember any of them talking about webhook...

Initially I was trying to deploy by using terraform or cloudformation. But could not figure out how to as most of tutorials were using eksctl. I could not find how to do the followings in cloudformation nor terraform. like `eksctl utils associate-iam-oidc-provider --region us-east-1 --cluster <cluster name> --approve` or creating service account
so I have started using eksctl and also to make its deployment work (regardless of this is what I want to do at the end or not).
I even removed the ecr repositry and set to `public.ecr.aws/l6m2t8p7/docker-2048:latest` to make it simple as possible.
but at this point, I have no clue how to make this situation simpler to debug and make the first simple application deployment worked....

any help or suggestions will be very very appreciated.

Also I intentionally did not use helm. I am new to kubernates and I did not want to over complicate it.
Once it resolve this, I am planning to use helm after doing enough research about it.